# Insert a directory at the start of a URL in Apache Config

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

Apologies if this question has already been asked before.  I couldn't find an example that handled my exact situation.

I have an Apache Server and have access to the httpd.conf file.

I have a domain (say www.example.com) and I want to insert a directory (say test) after the domain.
So for example I want www.example.com to be mapped to www.example.com/test and www.example.com/folder to be mapped to www.example.com/test/folder and so on.

I have achieved this using the a RedirectMatch directive like this:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
RedirectMatch ^/$ test/
</VirtualHost>
```

However this changes the URL in the browser to include the test folder and I would like to keep this hidden from the end user.

I have tried using a rewrite rule but my lack of regex knowledge has let me down here! This is what I have tried (within the virtual host element):-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1
```

I have tried various combinations with this but nothing seems to work!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem here.  This was working ok but my browser cache (Firefox) was remembering the old values.

I turned of caching in the browser (by going to about:config and setting browser.cache.disk.enable = FALSE

Then everything started working correctly.

Hopefully this will help others who have the same issue!